# How to use custom sampling when using special gnuplot filenames

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use the `gnuplot` `smooth unwrap` filter on a function, so I am using the suggested method to utilize the special '+' filename. However, I am unable to get the sampling right. I expected the command

```
plot sample [x=-5:5] '+' using (atan2(x,-x)) smooth unwrap
```

to give me a plot where the function is plotted form -5 to 5. It gives me a plot where the function is plotted from 0 to 100 instead. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampling axes are 't' for 1D sampling,  'u' and 'v' for 2D sampling.
1D samples are generated as if they came from a file with the sample values in column 1, so you need a `using` specifier to plot rather than a dummy variable x.   Your command becomes

```
plot sample [t=-5:5] '+' using 1:(atan2($1, -$1)) smooth unwrap
```

Or, if you prefer

```
plot sample [t=-5:5] '+' using (t):(atan2(t, -t)) smooth unwrap
```

You might ask why `t` rather than `x`?    That is because the [x,y] coordinates generated from your sampling functions `x(t)` and `y(t)` could be anything.  You need to be able to set the x and y axis ranges to an appropriate region of the plane, which is something quite different than the range of generated t values.